# Only PATCH request is giving cors error and http verbs are working perfectly fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, cors

I'm using ExpressJS as backend framework and have enabled cors.

`app.use(cors());`

All other apis that are put, post, get, delete are working perfectly fine. But when I use patch method only that patch specific api gives CORS error. But when I change the PATCH to PUT it again works perfectly. I searched many solutions and I came across one solution that says add methods in CORS options.

```
app.use(cors({
  methods:['PATCH',"GET",'PUT','POST','HEAD','DELETE']
}));
```

But still no luck.

Following is the api if that produces error when used as PATCH, but works fine when used as PUT.
FYI it is accepting formdata and I'm using multer to parse formdata.

**Before**

```
.patch(
    multer.single("image"),
    async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const { schoolID } = req.params;
        const args = { ...req.body};

        if (req.file) {
          args.image = {
            path: req.file.path,
            type: req.file.mimetype,
          };
        }
        const data = await update(args);
        res.json(data);
      } catch (error) {
        next(error);
      }
    }
  )
```

**After**

```
.put(
    multer.single("image"),
    async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const args = { ...req.body};

        if (req.file) {
          args.image = {
            path: req.file.path,
            type: req.file.mimetype,
          };
        }
        const data = await update(args);
        res.json(data);
      } catch (error) {
        next(error);
      }
    }
  )
```

This is the error that I'm getting when making PATCH request from frontend.
[image: Error]

Tried many different solutions but no luck.

Also tried with Origin as wild card "*" and with default configuration but still no luck

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it due to preflight request? Do you see any preflight request being send?

Comment: I think yes. This is the error when making a request from frontend.
"Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response."

Comment: I have included error image in question description. Thanks

Comment: Can you try including OPTIONS as well in the methods list?

Comment: Okay, I will try adding OPTIONS in methods, but as stated in cors docs I tried this but didn't work "app.options('*', cors())". This note might be helpful
"NOTE: When using this middleware as an application level middleware (for example, app.use(cors())), pre-flight requests are already handled for all routes."

Comment: When I use `app.use(cors())`, the PATCH preflight response has `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE` and it works.

Comment: Hmm. Strange, I don't know whats happening. Anyways thanks all.

Comment: I just noticed in Chrome I am not getting PATCH in Allowed-Methods however in Firefox it's working fine.